# Файл капчи не выдает картинку

Tags: php

Залил сайт на сервер. Появилась ВНЕЗАПНАЯ проблема с капчей. При появлении формы вместо капчи - картинка, указывающая наверняка, что файл-картинка не найден. При обновлении капчи картинка, наконец, появляется.
html-код капчи :`<img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" />`

Обновление капчи (js):

```
  img.src = "captcha.php?number=" + parseInt(Math.random()*1000);
```

Этот код прекрасно работает в Денвере, в чем же дело? Куда пропадает файл при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. @Deus, попытайтесь более детально описать, что не так. Забудьте о вашем проекте и перечитайте вопрос. Что происходит, что за картинка, которая указывает, что файл не найден, при каком обновлении капчи(обновлении версии? обновлении самой картинки капчи?) картинка наконец появляется? О чем это вы?  Код что вы выложили не о чем не говорит. Нужны логи. Там всегда есть ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, что обратили внимание, все нормально, просто сайт только залил, а они там еще наверное с путями не разобрались, только что проверил - капча есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, конечно, не телепат. Но очень сильно подозреваю, что в captcha.php есть нечто вроде:

```
if( isset($_GET['number']) )
{
 /* показать капчу с числом */
}
```

Поэтому предлагаю самостоятельно заглянуть в исходник капчи и пропробовать ответить на свой же вопрос. И/или для начала заглянуть в логи сервера, поискать там строчки с captcha.php и помедитировать над ними. И/или запустить [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) -S http://test.ru/captcha.php и помедитировать над увиденным...

Comment: @klopp, все ок. Проблема была не в коде, а на сервере, спасибо.